# Edit delete in webgrid Asp.net MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created webgrid table and it is fetching data from SQL View (data is coming from database view) everything is working fine except edit and delete. Getting error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The number of primary key values passed must
>   match a number of primary key values defined on the entity.

how can I fix it? I know I can not add a Primary key in View but I just tried to add Primary key on ID column but it did not let me do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception message, for example, the entity being updated has 2 columns that are the primary key, but only 1 is being passed in or vice versa.  It's hard to tell without seeing any code though.

The view shouldn't matter about whether a primary key exists or not; the controller should be the main component that is in play here?

Comment: yes there are 2 primary key EmployeeID and documentID and I am using employee ID....How can I past screen shot of code and error?

Comment: You also have to pass DocumentID as well.  Just copy relevant source code and use the formatting tool SO has....  Why, in this instance can't you also update DocumentID?